# Objective-C math function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I want square the number.using pow(). So,pow(3,2) should be 9.But it showing 8 in my iOS Calculator application.here is my code:

```
else if([opertaion isEqualToString:@"sqrt"])
    {

       result=pow([self popOperand],[self popOperand]);
    }
```

**method**

```
-(double)popOperand
{
    NSNumber *operandObject = [self.operandStack lastObject];
    if(operandObject)[self.operandStack removeLastObject];
    return [operandObject doubleValue];
}
```

One thing,I'm newibe on iOS programming.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect you aren't popping the values off your stack in the order that you think you are.

Comment: I Solved my problem.Please see the comment below.Thank you:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine you're just thinking about your operands backwards. 2^3 == 8.

Comment: Yes,I got it.I pressed 3^2.that's why i think it should be 9.Thank you:-)

Comment: @YasirAdnan If this answered your question, you really should accept it by clicking on the tick under the reputation spinner.

Answer (score 0):

```
 result=pow([self popOperand],[self popOperand]);
This statement is being executed from left to right ... so its calculating pow(2,3)

You can use 
double x = [self operand];
double y = [self operand];
result = pow(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to pop the first number then the last.  So, getPower(3,2) would come up as 2^3 instead.  I would look at your stack and make sure that you are arranging them correctly.